# Template function argument deduction with an implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

I understand that template function argument deduction does not take implicit conversions into account.

So this code doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct A {};
struct B : public A<int> {};
struct C {
  operator B() { return {}; }
};

template<class X>
void test(A<X> arg1, A<X> arg2) {
  std::cout << "ok1";
}

int main() {
  B b;
  C c;
  test(b, c);  // error: no matching function for call to 'test'
}
```

What I don't understand is how adding an extra level of indirection with an **identity `typedef`** somehow makes it work:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct A {};
struct B : public A<int> {};
struct C {
  operator B() { return {}; }
};

template<typename U> struct magic { typedef U type; };

template<class T> using magic_t = typename magic<T>::type;

template<class X>
void test(A<X> arg1, A<X> arg2) {
  std::cout << "ok1";
}

template<class X>
void test(A<X> arg3, magic_t<A<X>> arg4) {
  std::cout << "ok2";
}

int main() {
  B b;
  C c;
  test(b, c);  // prints "ok2"
}
```

[Live demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/v9BTPr)

How does `magic_t<A<X>>` end up matching `C`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter becomes [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) and doesn't participate in template argument deduction. `X` is then successfully deduced from the first argument.

Comment: How compiler is allowed to do two conversions? Or are derived to base conversions not counted?

Comment: @Incomputable I'm not sure I understand the question. Which two conversions are you talking about, from what to what else?

Comment: From c to b, then from b to a.

Comment: @Incomputable An implicit conversion sequence cannot have more than one *user-defined* conversion. It may involve multiple standard conversions. Derived-to-base is a standard conversion.

Comment: @Incomputable You can read more on Igor's statement in the corresponding [standardese](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv#7). There is also a [nice table in the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.ics.scs) for the rank of conversions.

Comment: To further clarify for anyone else reading, `test(c, b)` will not compile either in the second example because C is not derived from A<T>. Even adding a user-defined conversion from a C to A<T> does not work because [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) are not considered during type deduction. Thus, no type can be deduced.

Comment: Also, [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848619/template-deduction-why-it-works-with-inheritance-when-it-fails-with-conversion) did a good job providing a more precise explanation and standard reference about template deduction with arguments that are derived classes.